# stop to visibile past date from today angularjs

Tags: angularjs

future-only: I want to set forces validation errors on dates earlier than now

But it does not work please suggest thanks

```
<input
                      type="text"
                      datetime-picker
                      date-format="dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm a"
                      future-only
                      name="flightarrivaltime"
                      ng-model="users.flightarrivaltime"
                      required>

angular.module('Options', ['angularjs-datetime-picker'])
  .controller('Options', ['$rootScope', '$scope',  function ($rootScope, $scope) {

  }]);
```

Also can allow user to set month

Comment: Use **validators**: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

Answer (score 0):

It will still show all past dates according to 
https://github.com/kineticsocial/angularjs-datetime-picker
but if a earlier date is select the form will be invalid

The following is a solution to your problem: 
https://github.com/720kb/angular-datepicker

JS

```
$scope.MinDate = new Date(); 
$scope.Date = null;
```

HTML

```
<datepicker><input ng-model="date" date-min-limit="MinDate" type="text"/></datepicker>
```